# Is Redis security weak but does not matter?

Tags: redis

Considering [Redis Security Document](https://redis.io/topics/security), is my thoughts right?

1. Redis does not provide strong security functions by itself.
2. Redis already assumes that only trusted Redis clients are connecting in a secured network.
3. Simple security setting, for example, IP restriction settings in OS firewall is a way.

I don't think that Redis security is wrong. Basically, Redis is a backend program in a private network, just like Database servers are.

Comment: YES, YES and YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis security is weak, but security does matter.

It can be observed from the document itself that different methods are mentioned to address the weak points, such as, implementing authentication.

It is also mentioned that the "Redis is not optimized for maximum security but for maximum performance and simplicity". Hence, it is up to the developer to implement the security.